# Android Studio Language Injection

Tags: android, android-studio

I accidentally click Language Injection and change something which I didn't notice. Now I have problem with rendering xmls in Android Studio. How to get back with default settings ?

**SOLUTION:**

It's very simple. If you accidentally add language injection in some lines of xml code, you have to use shortcut **ALT + ENTER** on each of this lines, and select Delete Language Injection.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: not sure about Apple. See if you have a folder called (.AndroidStudio). on OSX a folder with a dot in front is a hidden folder.  Back it up some were just incase and then delete the original. That should reset AS